# How to change CSS Bootstrap style using JavaScript dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this style in my custom css stylesheet:

```
.nav.nav-tabs > li > a {
    background-color: #c6dfff;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}
```

I have a button using AngularJS ng-click:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
```

When the user clicks on the button, it calls a changeColor method:

```
            $scope.changeColor= function () {
                // Change Color Here
            };
```

I want to dynamically change the background-color of the above listed style to a different color.

Comment: You haven't met the minimum requirements for a question. Please show 1) your HTML snippet, and 2) what you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I was able to change my body background color using:  document.body.style.background = "whateverColor";   However, I wasn't sure how to change any style, not just the nav-tabs, via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

alright, so If you want to use javascript, you could do this one of two ways. The first would be to assign the object an ID, or if multiple objects you would use a class.

for an ID

```
document.getElementById("myId").style.backgroundColor="yourcolor"
```

replace your color with the color you want and myID with the ID of the object. If you have multiple objects with the same class,

for a class

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myclassname").style.backgroundColor="yourcolor"
```

again, replace the myclassname with the name of the class; same for your color

or if you want to use JQuery

```
$(".myclassname").css("background-color", "your color");
```

typically, you use classes for multiple items, and IDs for single ones. feel free to comment and Ill add anything else you need; as i am a little uncertain of the specifics of what you are asking.

Comment: Tried the JQuery method and it didn't work. I need to set the class for the active tab:   $(".nav.nav-tabs > li > a").css("background-color", "red");

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected value from dropdown, either by using `onchange` on the `select` or in a button click. Then use the value to assign it to the background of the element you want.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="bgselect" onchange="changeBg()">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="#000080">Navy Blue</option>
    ...
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function changeBg() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("bgselect").value;
    document.getElementById("dbg").style.background = bg;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gxj4ep56/2/)

**EDIT:**

If you wanna affect elements like `.nav.nav-tabs > li > a` then you need to find all such elements and then apply the style:

```
function changeBg() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("bgselect").value;
    var navs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav.nav-tabs");
    var as = navs[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        as[i].style.background = bg;
    }
}
```

[**updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gxj4ep56/3/)

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for; However, the style that I need to change is the one listed in my post:   .nav.nav-tabs > li > a